# Rooster-react set ribbon theming based on fluent ui theme provider

Tags: reactjs, theming, fluentui-react, roosterjs, roosterjs-react

### Problem

I'm working on a react app (CRA) with [rooster](https://github.com/microsoft/roosterjs)-react, which utilizes @fluentui, so I was trying to set the theme of the toolbar using the respective theme provider, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

### Steps

I created a new project from scratch to figure out what the problem, with no avail, here are the steps I followed:

1. Created a react app with CRA 5

```bash
npx create-react-app test --template typescript
```

2. Installed the following packages:

```json
"@fluentui/react": "8.112.6",
"roosterjs": "^8.54.0",
"roosterjs-editor-types": "^8.54.0",
"roosterjs-react": "^8.51.0",
```

3. Edited the package @fluentui/react-portal-compat-context in package-lock.json to 9.0.6 as instructed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/29107#issuecomment-1721310081)
4. Created the following component

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { IEditor, getDarkColor } from "roosterjs";
import {
  createRibbonPlugin,
  getButtons,
  Ribbon,
  RibbonButton,
  Rooster,
  AllButtonKeys,
} from "roosterjs-react";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Icons";
import { ThemeProvider, DefaultPalette } from "@fluentui/react";

const darkPalette = Object.entries(DefaultPalette).reduce(
  (result, [name, color]) => ({ ...result, [name]: getDarkColor(color) }),
  { ...DefaultPalette }
);

initializeIcons();

export function RoosterEditor({ value }: {value?: string) {
  const themeMode = "dark"; // using a custom provider with a different name + hook in the actual code
  const ribbonPlugin = useMemo(createRibbonPlugin, []);
  const plugins = useMemo(() => [ribbonPlugin], [ribbonPlugin]);
  const buttons = useMemo(() => getButtons(AllButtonKeys), []) as RibbonButton<string>[];

  const inDarkMode = themeMode === "dark";
  const themePalette = inDarkMode ? darkPalette : DefaultPalette;
  const theme = { palette: themePalette };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme} applyTo="body">
      <Ribbon plugin={ribbonPlugin} buttons={buttons} />
      <Rooster plugins={plugins} initialContent={value} inDarkMode={inDarkMode} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

5. Updated index.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RoosterEditor } from "./RoosterEditor";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(<React.StrictMode><RoosterEditor /></React.StrictMode>);
```

### Samples

I created a sample [repo](https://github.com/nickzoum/react-rooster-test/) and [Netlify](https://effulgent-llama-b686e9.netlify.app/) example which don't seem to work:

But when I copied an empty react application sandbox and followed the same steps it worked, you can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-wilbur-jp3v7n?file=/package.json).

You can also check the official demo [here](https://microsoft.github.io/roosterjs/index.html) (the theme mode toggle is one of the last buttons on the ribbon).

What am I doing wrong with the blank CRA project?

Comment: ```ThemeProvider``` from ```@fluentui/react``` is **primarily** used to provide a theme to Fluent UI components, and it doesn't directly affect the styling of non-Fluent UI components like the Rooster toolbar.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation I'm fairly certain that rooster using the theme provider context since it works on their demo page and the sandbox

Comment: It's possible that the Rooster toolbar is indeed using the theme context provided by ```ThemeProvider```. Sometimes provides a theme to its child components. These child components can then use the theme for their own styling. However, the way the theme is applied depends on how the child components are implemented. Some components might use the theme directly, while others might use it to generate CSS classes or inline styles.[Ref](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/How-to-apply-theme-to-Fluent-UI-React-components)

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation So if the source files are identical why would it work in the sandbox and not in the local cra app?

Comment: Maybe this could be due to the different build configurations between the sandbox and your local CRA. Even though the source files are identical, the way they're built and served can affect how they behave. Example *1. Different package versions 2. CRA's build process 3. Environment variables and 4.CSS scoping*

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation The package versions are identical, and as far as I can tell the classnames of the buttons change with the theme, which doesn't happen in the cra app so it's probably not a css scoping issue. I suspect it has something to do with the build process but what part of it is causing the issue I have no of fixing it.